# Angular 2: How to check if running app using "ng serve"

Tags: angular

Is there any sort of flag or global node variable available that tells you whether or not you are using `ng serve` to run Angular?

Need this for development purposes, just need a flag of some sort.

Comment: check the link on which it is deployed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

...

if(isDevMode()) { ...
```

https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode

might work for you, but it doesn't actually tell if it is served by `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your apps such that they are always served on `localhost:4xxx` urls, then you could check for that and provide that as an injection token.

Declare and register (e.g. in app.module.ts):

```
export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

export function isWatchEnvironment() {
    return getBaseUrl().indexOf("localhost:4") >= 0;
}

export const API_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');
export const IS_WATCH_ENVIRONMENT = new InjectionToken<boolean>('IS_WATCH_ENVIRONMENT');

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: API_BASE_URL, useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] },
        { provide: IS_WATCH_ENVIRONMENT, useFactory: isWatchEnvironment, deps: [] },
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Use it somewhere:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyEnvironmentAwareService {
    isWatchEnvironment = inject(IS_WATCH_ENVIRONMENT);
    ...
}
```

(Note you can skip registering `API_BASE_URL` if not applicable)